# Why is my react useState variable "topicList" updating even though I'm not calling setTopicList()?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react and am working on creating a basic to do list with list elements that can be reordered. The code I wrote works as I intended, but I am having trouble understanding why. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function TopicInput() {
    const [topicText,setTopicText] = useState("");
    const [topicList,setTopicList] = useState([]);
    const [topicCount,setTopicCount] = useState(0); 
    const [lastDeterminedOrder,setLastDeterminedOrder] = useState(0);
    var updateText = (e) => {
        setTopicText(e.target.value);
        console.log(topicText);
    }
    var updateList = (e) => {
        console.log("topic text is: "+topicText);
        setTopicList([...topicList,[1+Math.random(),topicText,0,0,topicCount+1]]);
        console.log(topicList);
        setTopicText("");
        setTopicCount(topicCount+1);
    }
    var removeItem = (e,id) => {
        var list = [...topicList];
        var updatedList = list.filter(i=>i[0]!=id);
        console.log("first updated list",updatedList);
        setTopicList(updatedList);
        setTopicCount(topicCount-1);
        console.log("the topic list",updatedList);
        var deletedCount = getCountByID(id);
        resetCountsBelowDeleted(deletedCount);
        console.log("deleted count value",getCountByID(id));
        console.log("state here: ",topicList);
    }
    var updateBounds = () => {
        for(var i=0;i<topicCount;i++)
        {
            var currentElement = document.getElementById((topicList[i][0]).toString());
            topicList[i][2] = currentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            topicList[i][3] = currentElement.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
        }
        console.log(topicList);
    }
    var handleDocMove = (e) => {
        console.log("doc mouse move");
        console.log(e.pageY);
        var currentOrder = determineOrder(e.pageY);
        if(LastDeterminedOrder.ldo==undefined)LastDeterminedOrder(currentOrder);
        if(LastDeterminedOrder.ldo!=currentOrder&&currentOrder!=undefined)
        {
            var priorOrder = LastDeterminedOrder.ldo;
            LastDeterminedOrder(currentOrder);
            console.log("order changed from "+(priorOrder).toString()+" to "+(LastDeterminedOrder.ldo).toString());
            listStateSwap(priorOrder,LastDeterminedOrder.ldo);
        }
        console.log("last determined order: "+(LastDeterminedOrder.ldo).toString());
        console.log(currentOrder);
        // document.removeEventListener("mousemove",handleDocMove);
        // document.addEventListener("mousemove",handleDocMove);
    }
    var listStateSwap = (prior,ldo) => {
        var priorID = getIDByCount(prior);
        var priorText = getTextByCount(prior);
        var ldoID = getIDByCount(ldo);
        var ldoText = getTextByCount(ldo);
        console.log("right here first: ",topicList[prior-1][1]);
        var newtopicList = [...topicList];
        newtopicList[prior-1][0] = ldoID;//
        newtopicList[prior-1][1] = ldoText;
        // newtopicList[prior-1][4] = ldo;
        newtopicList[ldo-1][0] = priorID;
        newtopicList[ldo-1][1] = priorText;
        // newtopicList[ldo-1][4] = prior;
        setTopicList(newtopicList);
        console.log("right here: ",topicList[prior-1][1]);
    }
    var getCountByID = (id) => {
        for(var k=0;k<topicCount;k++)
        {
            if(topicList[k][0]==id)
            {
                // console.log("right here...",topicList[k][4]);
                return topicList[k][4];
            }
        }
    }
    var getIDByCount = (count) => {
        for(var k=0;k<count;k++)
        {
            if(topicList[k][4]==count)
            {
                // console.log("right here...",topicList[k][4]);
                return topicList[k][0];
            }
        }
    }
    var getTextByCount = (count) => {
        for(var k=0;k<count;k++)
        {
            if(topicList[k][4]==count)
            {
                return topicList[k][1];
            }
        }
    }
    var LastDeterminedOrder = (last) => {
        LastDeterminedOrder.ldo = last;
    }
    var determineOrder = (pageY) => {
        for(var j=0;j<topicCount;j++)
        {
            if(pageY>=topicList[j][2]&&pageY<=topicList[j][3])
            {
                return topicList[j][4];
            }
        }
    }   
    var handleDocMouseUp = () => {
        console.log("mouseupfired");
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove",handleDocMove);
        document.removeEventListener("mouseup",handleDocMouseUp);
    }
    var handleMouseDown = () => {
        console.log("mousedown fired");
        document.addEventListener("mousemove",handleDocMove);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup",handleDocMouseUp);
    }
    var resetCountsBelowDeleted = (deletedcount) => {
        var newList = [...topicList];
        for(var i=0;i<newList.length;i++)
        {
            if(newList[i][4]>deletedcount)
            {   
                newList[i][4] = newList[i][4]-1;
            }
        }
        console.log("newlist: ",newList);
        // setTopicList(newList);
    }   
    useEffect(()=>{
        updateBounds();
        // listStateSwap(1,2);
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a new topic" onChange={updateText} value={topicText}/>
            <button onClick={updateList}>Add</button> 
            <ul>
                {topicList.map((item,index)=>{
                    return (
                        <li key={item[0]} id={(item[0]).toString()}>{item[1]}
                        <span onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}>  |Reorder|  </span>
                        <button onClick={(e)=>{removeItem(e,item[0])}}>X</button>
                        </li>
                    )
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I didn't expect the above code to work, but it did. The reason I didn't expect it to work is because I thought that since I have the setTopicList(newList); line commented out in the resetCountsBelowDeleted function (line 135), that the topicList state wouldn't update, and therefore I expected that after deleting a list item, I wouldn't see the last element from the topicList lists update correctly. But somehow, the state did change even though this line was commented out and the counts got updated correctly.

So my question is: How did my resetCountsBelowDeleted function correctly update my topicList state even though I had setTopicList(newList) commented out? Also, why do the delete buttons stop working correctly when I don't comment this line out? I believe the code I wrote is more complicated than it should be for this relatively simple application, so any suggestions on how to simplify this and make it cleaner would be appreciated!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `[...topicList]` creates a shallow copy of the array, meaning that the objects in `newArray` still refer to the original objects in `topicList`. Therefore when you make changes to the objects in `newArray` you are changing the objects in topicList